# Generating Excel Sheet (CSV) via PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have a php logic which generate excel sheets by retriving data from MYSQL database table. There is no issues in generating and viewing the file but I would like to get to know more about accessing and assigning data for cell values without just having the data boldly there.

Accessing cell values and providing some styles for those cells

The logic so far is as follow,

```
if (isset($_POST['maintainexcel'])) {
$sqlmaintain = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$employeeid";
$resultmain = mysqli_query($connect,$sqlmaintain);
if ($resultmain->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($rowmainexcel = $resultmain->fetch_assoc()) {
        $empnameforexcelmain = $rowmainexcel['name'];
        $maintainexcel = "SELECT * FROM `maintenance` WHERE user_id = $employeeid";
        $resultmain = mysqli_query($connect,$maintainexcel);
        $itemsmain = array();
        
        //Store table records into an array
        while( $rowmain = $resultmain->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $itemsmain[] = $rowmain;
        }
        //Check the export button is pressed or not
        if(isset($_POST["maintainexcel"])) {
            //Define the filename with current date
            $fileNamemain = "Maintenance Data of $empnameforexcelmain - ".date('d-m-Y').".xls";
            
            //Set header information to export data in excel format
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileNamemain);
            //Set variable to false for heading
            $headingmain = false;
            
            //Add the MySQL table data to excel file
            if(!empty($itemsmain)) {
                foreach($itemsmain as $item2) {
                    if(!$headingmain) {
                        echo implode("\t",array_keys($item2))."\n";                            
                    }
                    
                    echo implode("\t",array_values($item2));
                }
            }
            exit();
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

So far this code generates a excel sheet as shown below

[image: Generated Excel Sheet]

So, in order to adjust the sheet with some additional text if i change the code

```
//Add the MySQL table data to excel file
            if(!empty($itemsmain)) {
                foreach($itemsmain as $item2) {
                    if(!$headingmain) {
                        echo implode("\t",array_keys($item2))."\n";                            
                    }
                    
                    echo implode("\t",array_values($item2));
                }
            }
```

to

```
//Add the MySQL table data to excel file
            if(!empty($itemsmain)) {
                foreach($itemsmain as $item2) {
                    if(!$headingmain) {
                        echo implode("\r",array_keys($item2))."\n";                            
                    }
                    
                    echo implode("\r",array_values($item2));
                }
            }
```

Every data is stacked vertically on just one cell tab (A1), how can i place the data in the excel sheet in specific excel cells and add more static data to the sheet without colliding with the dynamically fetched data

Comment: This code doesn't generate an excel sheet, it generates a tab-delimited file with a fake extension and fake mime type. Excel can read such files, but they are not in the full Excel format, and lack many features by comparison. I suggest using a library which can generate real Excel files, it will give you much more flexibility about how you create the file (such as writing to specific cells out of sequence) and other things such as visual formatting options etc.

Comment: Be carefull when putting variables directly in your query, if it is user input by any way it is SQL injectionable. I'd recommend to bind all your values, even if they are not user input

Comment: @Timberman Nope user input is not taken just a generate file button click and this file gets generated

Comment: @ADyson Well noted, will look into some libraries which can help me in this

Comment: @Developer Where does $employeeid come from?

Comment: @Timberman The employees id is fetched from the login session based on the id logging into the system other functionalities work

Comment: I'd always recommend binding variables, if a hacker has access to changing the sessions, a misconfiguration on the site or knows how to bypass anything like that, he still won't be able to do anything vulnerable.